# Wordpress php memory. Загрузка csv файла

Tags: php, wordpress

Использую плагин `wp ultimate csv importer` для импорта `csv` файла в `wordpress`.
Суть в том, что `csv` файлы объемом в 50кб он грузит, а в 4мб выдает как 0 байт, то есть не принимает.
Почему может быть так?
Читал на форумах поддержки о `php memory`. Может быть на этом все держится?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо увеличить лимиты на загружаемые файлы.
Вроде как достаточно в конфиге (`php.ini`) увеличить значения `post_max_size` и `upload_max_filesize`.
Может быть еще что-то, точно уже не помню. Ну и апач перезагрузить после всего надо.

Comment: @BOPOH, спасибо большое!, http://rcreated.com/blog/raznoe/gde-php-ini/ находим расположение php.ini и меняем  post_max_size и upload_max_filesize